# jQuery UI Sortable linked elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two columns, each with many rows/divs.  I'm trying to get jQuery UI Sortable to work in a way that if I drag a div in the left column, the associated row/div in the right column will be sorted as well.

For example,

```
<html><body>
  <div class='left-column'>
    <div class='field' id='left_1'>content 1</div>
    <div class='field' id='left_2'>content 2</div>
    <div class='field' id='left_3'>content 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class='right-column'>
    <div class='field' id='right_1'>content 1</div>
    <div class='field' id='right_2'>content 2</div>
    <div class='field' id='right_3'>content 3</div>
  </div>
</body></html>
```

As for the jQuery, right now I have,

```
function linkedSort() {
  $('.left-column').sortable({ 
    axis: 'y',
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      $('.left-column .field').each(function(i, field) {
        var fieldName = $(field).attr('id');
        var fieldNumber = fieldName.substr(fieldName.indexOf('_')+1);
        // do something here to place it in the right area
      });
    }
  });
};
```

If I drag .left-column .field_2 below .field_3, the respective divs in .right-column should rearrange themselves as well.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid your question, in its current form, only amounts to markup and boilerplate code. Did you try anything at all? Please post code from your (even incomplete or incorrect) attempts to solve this problem; that will help us tune the solution to your specific use case.

Comment: Sorry, first time asking a question on StackOverflow.  Also, pretty new to jQuery and Javascript, so please excuse my coding.  

I was hoping there was a built-in solution by jQuery UI so I didn't think what I've done was important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might be what you are looking for:

```
<div class='left-column'>
    <div name='field_1'>content 1</div>
    <div name='field_2'>content 2</div>
    <div name='field_3'>content 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class='right-column'>
    <div name='field_1'>content 1</div>
    <div name='field_2'>content 2</div>
    <div name='field_3'>content 3</div>
</div>

$('.left-column').sortable({
    axis: 'y',
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        $('.left-column div[name^=field_]').each(function(i, v) {
            $('.right-column').find("[name=" + $(v).attr('name') + "]").appendTo($('.right-column'));
        });
    }
});
$('.right-column').disableSelection();
```